# Blank page "redirecting to..." message

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Every time I return a redirect to a route from a certain controller, the redirect is always preceded with the following message:

Redirecting to 
`https://localhost`....

It shows that for about a few seconds and the redirect is completed.Has anyone every had this error before?

It shows up for every redirect in my controller so I thought it would be illogical to add my whole controller but if you need to see the controller then please comment.

Comment: Can you post your `filters.php` file?

Answer (score 1):

Someone on another forum pointed out that issue was that there was an extra space in front of my php tag. I removed it and now it works perfectly!

Comment: extra space infront of opening tag or closing tag?  i too encounter this issue in my project but can't figured out at where the actual problem is